# need explaining code: Repeating Nth element in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm writing a program to repeat an element in Prolog, for example

```
repeat_nth(1, [H|T], [H,H|T]).
repeat_nth(N, [H|T], [H|T1]) :-
    N > 1,
    N1 is N-1,
    repeat_nth(N1, T, T1).
```

I can understand everything on here up until the last line. If anyone could explain in simple terms what's happening that'd be great. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening on the last line is recursion. Suppose we make the call `repeat_nth(2, [1,2,3], X)`. 2 is not 1 so we enter the second rule. Now 2 is greater than 1, so we calcuate N1 as N-1. N1 will therefore equal 1. The last line will therefore be the call `repeat_nth(1, [2,3], T1)`. From there, we will enter the first rule, and unify T1 with `[2,2,3]`. Returning to the call site in the second rule, nothing more needs to be done, and X will be unified with `[1,2,2,3]`.

You may find it helps to call `trace, repeat_nth(2, [1,2,3], X).`, or try other queries with `trace`, to see what Prolog does. It shows you exactly what happens like this:

```
?- trace, repeat_nth(2, [1,2,3], X).
   Call: (7) repeat_nth(2, [1, 2, 3], _G1360) ? 
   Call: (8) 2>1 ? 
   Exit: (8) 2>1 ? 
   Call: (8) _G1492 is 2+ -1 ? 
   Exit: (8) 1 is 2+ -1 ? 
   Call: (8) repeat_nth(1, [2, 3], _G1480) ? 
   Exit: (8) repeat_nth(1, [2, 3], [2, 2, 3]) ? 
   Exit: (7) repeat_nth(2, [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3]) ? 
X = [1, 2, 2, 3]
```

If you can follow my explanation, you can probably follow the trace output as well.